# Errors when running tiktok-hashtag-analysis by bellingcat

Tags: python

Has anyone used the [tiktok-hashtag-analysis tool by bellingcat](https://pypi.org/project/tiktok-hashtag-analysis/2.0.3/)? I've been getting errors when running the code and reaching for guidance.

I satisfied all their pre-requisites. I have limited Python experience and am at a loss on how to fix the errors. The exact code I ran is:

```
username-MacBook-Pro:pythonScript username$ tiktok-hashtag-analysis japan paris
```

The exact errors that I am getting are:

```
2024-02-29 20:37:04 INFO | Writing data to directory: /Users/username/tiktok_hashtag_data
2024-02-29 20:37:25 WARNING | Encountered error None -> TikTok returned an empty response when fetching data, retrying in headed mode
2024-02-29 20:37:38,637 - TikTokApi.tiktok - ERROR - Got an unexpected status code: {'log_pb': {'impr_id': '20240301013738A2B73E65CF69CD0E9B9E'}, 'statusCode': 10201, 'statusMsg': '', 'status_code': 10201, 'status_msg': ''}
2024-02-29 20:37:38,637 - TikTokApi.tiktok - ERROR - Got an unexpected status code: {'log_pb': {'impr_id': '20240301013738A2B73E65CF69CD0E9B9E'}, 'statusCode': 10201, 'statusMsg': '', 'status_code': 10201, 'status_msg': ''}
2024-02-29 20:37:38 ERROR | Got an unexpected status code: {'log_pb': {'impr_id': '20240301013738A2B73E65CF69CD0E9B9E'}, 'statusCode': 10201, 'statusMsg': '', 'status_code': 10201, 'status_msg': ''}
2024-02-29 20:37:38 WARNING | No posts were found for the hashtag: japan
2024-02-29 20:37:38 INFO | Scraped 0 new posts containing the hashtag 'japan', with 0 posts previously scraped
2024-02-29 20:37:47 WARNING | Encountered error None -> TikTok returned an empty response when fetching data, retrying in headed mode
2024-02-29 20:37:59,122 - TikTokApi.tiktok - ERROR - Got an unexpected status code: {'log_pb': {'impr_id': '20240301013759BC4F3F89CAFA6A0E1FF2'}, 'statusCode': 10201, 'statusMsg': '', 'status_code': 10201, 'status_msg': ''}
2024-02-29 20:37:59,122 - TikTokApi.tiktok - ERROR - Got an unexpected status code: {'log_pb': {'impr_id': '20240301013759BC4F3F89CAFA6A0E1FF2'}, 'statusCode': 10201, 'statusMsg': '', 'status_code': 10201, 'status_msg': ''}
2024-02-29 20:37:59,122 - TikTokApi.tiktok - ERROR - Got an unexpected status code: {'log_pb': {'impr_id': '20240301013759BC4F3F89CAFA6A0E1FF2'}, 'statusCode': 10201, 'statusMsg': '', 'status_code': 10201, 'status_msg': ''}
2024-02-29 20:37:59,122 - TikTokApi.tiktok - ERROR - Got an unexpected status code: {'log_pb': {'impr_id': '20240301013759BC4F3F89CAFA6A0E1FF2'}, 'statusCode': 10201, 'statusMsg': '', 'status_code': 10201, 'status_msg': ''}
2024-02-29 20:37:59 ERROR | Got an unexpected status code: {'log_pb': {'impr_id': '20240301013759BC4F3F89CAFA6A0E1FF2'}, 'statusCode': 10201, 'statusMsg': '', 'status_code': 10201, 'status_msg': ''}
2024-02-29 20:37:59 WARNING | No posts were found for the hashtag: paris
2024-02-29 20:37:59 INFO | Scraped 0 new posts containing the hashtag 'paris', with 0 posts previously scraped
```

More context: 1. I use MacOS, and 2. Whenever I run the code in the terminal, it opens the TikTok page in Chromium incognito, and I am not logged into Tiktok.